# when I make def and assign some parameter using spark.sql , I get back empty dataframe in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

When I make def and assign some parameter,somehow doesn't work in pyspark.

```
def Get_Data(dapature_time)

data = spark.sql( 
      """SELECT id, 
         FROM datalake where (departure_time >='{}').format(departure_time) """
```

It work on separeatly with specific time, but doesnt works in def function with parameter

How do I pass prameter properly?

I've got tuple index out of range error

hard coding
put paramerter by hands

Answer (score 0):

wrong indentation.

```
def Get_Data(dapature_time)
    data = spark.sql( 
      """SELECT id, 
         FROM datalake where (departure_time >='{}').format(departure_time) """
```